# BluetoothGattCallback's onCharacteristicChanged not triggered on Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-7.0-nougat, bluetooth-gatt

When communicating with my BLE device `onCharacteristicChanged` is trigged as expected for all versions of android prior to Android N. The issue is seen only on Android N.

For Android N `onCharacteristicChanged` is never triggered. Is there something that has changed in the way `BluetoothGattCallback` behaves on Android Nougat?

Initialization of descriptor:

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(MyDeviceUuid.CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
if (descriptor != null) {
            descriptor.setValue(enable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
```

Comment: How you are initializing BluetoothGattDescriptor? Post some code for more info.

Comment: Have you checked this?https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml&u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml

Comment: If possible, Kindly post value of CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID.